How to see Chrome tabs in order of last VIEWED?
In Chrome, on desktop at least, CTRL+H (chrome://history/) lists pages by time of tab creation.
That means that a (still open, but not current/main/in focus) tab that I was just looking at moments ago might be still buried deep in the list.
How can I find it? I've got too many tabs up there in the tab bar at the top of the screen to look through them one by one.

SHIFT+CTRL+A seems to do what you want!
(Opens "Search Tabs" ("V" at the upper left of your window.)
(That covers desktop. Mobile is a whole different story...)
